# Received message larger than max on a batch processing pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have been getting this message on a batch processing pipeline that has been running daily on google's cloud dataflow service. It has started failing with the following message:

```
(88b342a0e3852af3): java.io.IOException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Received message larger than max (21824326 vs. 4194304) 
dataflow-batch-jetty-11171129-7ea5-harness-waia talking to localhost:12346 at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ApplianceShuffleWriter.close(Native Method) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.close(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:67) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.close(ShuffleSink.java:286) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.finish(WriteOperation.java:100) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:264) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:197) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:149) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:192) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:173) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:160) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am still using an old workaround to output a CSV file with headers such as

```
PCollection<String> output = data.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
    String new_line = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String csv_header = "id, stuff_1, stuff_2" + new_line;
    StringBuilder csv_body = new StringBuilder().append(csv_header);

    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        csv_body.append(c.element()).append(newline);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishBundle(Context c) throws Exception {
        c.output(csv_body.toString());
    }

})).apply(TextIO.Write.named("WriteData").to(options.getOutput()));
```

What is causing this? Is the output of this DoFn too big now? The size of the dataset being processed has not increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it might be a bug on our side and we're looking into it, but in general the code is probably not doing what you intend it to do.

As written, you'll end up with an unspecified number of output files, whose names start with the given prefix, each file containing a concatenation of your expected CSV-like output (including headers) for different chunks of the data, in an unspecified order.

In order to properly implement writing to CSV files, simply use `TextIO.Write.withHeader()` to specify the header, and remove your CSV-constructing ParDo entirely. This will also not trigger the bug.

Comment: It is running on Google Cloud Dataflow Java SDK 1.5.0. I'm also aware of the new `TextIO.Write.withHeader()`, but I haven't yet updated the SDK or the code yet. I was just wondering why it started failing now.

Comment: It successfully ran on SDK versions 1.7.0 and 1.8.0. Now that I'm looking at the code it already had 1.7.0 on the `pom.xml` file. And I'm not sure if it would ran on 1.5.0 since I had already updated the code to run using the new v1 datastore API.

Comment: On why it started failing now: we're incrementally rolling out a performance improvement in shuffle, and your pipeline hit a bug in the improved version. We're working on a fix. So, I'm confused: is your problem fully resolved by using SDK 1.7.0/1.8.0 and TextIO.Write.withHeader()?

Comment: It has been solved by switching to 1.7.0/1.8.0 only. I haven't updated the code to use withHeader yet.

Comment: Most likely it hasn't actually been solved, your pipeline just wasn't randomly selected to use the buggy optimization this time.

Comment: hummm... the scheduled launch of this job from appengine flex ran for an hour instead of the usual 5 minutes and I had to kill it. job id 2016-11-18_11_29_14-9043658950083337798.

Comment: I'm investigating previous runs of this job and it seems like the SDK version kept changing. On November 1st ir ran on SDK 1.7 for the last time, then it switched to 1.6 from November 2nd to November 15th. Then it dropped down to 1.5 on the next day and failed with the reported message.

Comment: I looked at the stuck job. It looks like you have multiple SDK versions at the same time in your classpath (1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0), and this is causing all kinds of issues because the classpath order is non-deterministic. Please make sure you have only 1 version at a time.

Comment: Humm.. So that's what was causing it to run on different version. I'll check that.

Comment: You were right and my issue was resolved. Part of it was maven related then (pom.xml).